# Выбор файрвол + прокси

Tags: firewall, прокси, proxy

Сеть доменная, юзеров, серверов и машин не много. Kerio не предлагать, в данной ситуации это "по воробьям из пушки". Спасибо заранее всем откликнувшимся!

Comment: Файер - понятно. Но прокси зачем? Юзверям доступ резать?

Comment: Купи маршрутизатор там есть встроеный файер и прокси подджерживает

Comment: "Kerio не предлагать" -- зря, только пальцы нацелились на буквы "K", "e", "r", "i" и "o"...Позволю себе предположить, что в таком случае все будет "по воробьям из пушки"...

Comment: Уже стоит сервер, который выполняет эту роль

Comment: Ну вот настрой его как тебе надо

Comment: так в чём цель прокси? может он не нужен?

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, на мой взгляд нужно оговаривать бюджет, который готова или не готова потратить ваша организация на проект. Во-вторых, смею предложить отлично зарекомендовавший себя российский продукт Ideco Control Server. Есть возможность получения бесплатной версии на 5 пользователей. Продукт использует ядро linux. В случае ограниченного буджета или его полное отсутствие, постройте терминальный сервер на linux при помощи freenx. Есть еще масса всяких решений, но рекомендую вам составить более полное тех.задание, хотя бы количество тачек, которые нужно высунуть в сеть.

Answer (score 0):

Под какой ОСью сервер?

*nix-ы - [Netfilter](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter), форточки -Kerio, без ОСи - [Kerio](http://www.kerio.ru/ru/control/software-appliance) из [ISO](http://www.kerio.ru/download.php?server=us&product=kerio-control-installer.iso)